# DataStax Enterprise Portfolio Manager Demo Fails

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise

I am trying to experiment with Spark and found this demo provided by DataStax:
http://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.5/datastax_enterprise/anaHome/anaPortfolioMgrSpark.html

I was able to run the pricer utility and data populated into created tables without any issues.

Then next command is to start the website which I did:

```
$ cd website
$ sudo ./start
```

And then open the url on the browser:
http://localhost:8983/portfolio

The website appears to load but a script error comes up:

> fname is undefined

The initial error seems to stem from here:

```
  if (mtype == Thrift.MessageType.EXCEPTION) {
    var x = new Thrift.TApplicationException();
    x.read(this.input);
    this.input.readMessageEnd();
    throw x;
  }
```

The error is occurring in thrift.js and is shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

Any ideas on how to resolve this? I believe this is probably a bug (or limitation) that must be addressed by the DataStax team. I am using DSE on Ubuntu. **My best guess is because I don't use localhost in my cassandra.yaml file and the website gives me no way to specify the IP of my database server.** There appears to be a duplicate of the cassandra.yaml file in the website resource directory (maybe it uses that?) but it has the same settings as my primary cassandra.yaml file.

Comment: This is how they ask to be contacted unfortunately via their "tags".

Comment: Note the document you linked to - "Install Options page - Default Interface: 127.0.0.1 (You must use this IP for the demo.)"

Comment: Thanks somehow I missed that although I had a feeling that was it. I'll probably try setting my config to localhost temporarily and see how that goes :)